# A function that does not satisfy the first condition of metric but satisfies the others.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

Given a set $X$ I have to construct a function $d : X\times X\to \mathbb R$ such that $d(x,x)\neq 0$ for some $x$ and

$ 1. d(x,y)>0 \forall x\neq y$

$2.d(x,y)=d(y,x) \forall x,y \in X$

$3.d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \forall x,y,z \in X $
I could not come up with a general example for any set $X$ but for $X=\mathbb R^2$
I have taken $d(x,y)=e^x+e^y$.
Is it a correct one and how to do it for any set $X$?

Comment: Your question seems a little different from that of in the title. Could you clarify what do you want to ask?

Comment: @HanulJeon He wants to have such a function where $d(x,x)=0$ fails for some $x$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, I get it.

Comment: @HanulJeon Can I take the function $d(x,y)=2 $ if $x>y$,$d(x,y)=1$ if $x<y$ and 
 $d(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$ as an example where all conditions for metric holds except for the condition of symmetry?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can I take the function $d(x,y)=2 $ if $x>y$,$d(x,y)=1$ if $x<y$ and 
 $d(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$ as an example where all conditions for metric holds except for the condition of symmetry?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Yes, in 3. we then have at most 2 on the left and at least 2 on the right, so that always holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D$ is any metric then $d(x,y)=D(x,y)+1$ has those properties.